# Calling WordPress REST API from server

Tags: php, wordpress, rest

I have an application server written in PHP, and it needs to interact with a WordPress deployment through WP's REST API. I am having difficulty calling the WP's REST API with authentication. For example, how do I create a user after authenticated with WP?

Most of the examples I found online are either using Ajax or cookies for authentication, which don't work in the server situation.

Can anyone suggest?

Comment: We use php curl in invoking other php endpoints. I suggest you can look into it: http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you question is : how do I create a user after authenticated with WP?
I'm considering you don't have probem in the process of authentication.
If you use PHP you can use php file_get_contents function or cURL 
bellow I will give you an example with PHP cURL

```
$post = array(
'username'  => 'user2',
'email'     => 'user2@somedomain.com',
'password'  =>  'somerandompassword');

$post = http_build_query($post);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://localhost/wp/wp-json/wp/v2/users");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "username" . ":" . "password"
);
$headers    = array();
$headers[]  = "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close ($ch);
print_r(json_decode($result, true), true);
```

You also can use file_get_contents function if your server can't use cURL for some reasons. You can find another another example of WP REST API with php in here [www.wpsaga.info/tag/wp-rest-api](http://www.wpsaga.info/tag/wp-rest-api/)

Comment: It is worth pointing out that WordPress has some core functions for a remote call that I would use here instead of a manual cURL or file_get_contents call.https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_remote_post/